# Flutter - Remove default padding in Slider

Tags: flutter, dart, slider

I am wondering how I can remove the default padding in `Flutter Slider`

Current output is like this, **default padding** of Slider is clearly visible

[image]

Here's my code::

```
                    Positioned(
                      child: Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                        child: SliderTheme(
                            data: SliderTheme.of(context).copyWith(
                              trackHeight: 2.0,
                              thumbColor: Colors.transparent,
                              thumbShape: RoundSliderThumbShape(enabledThumbRadius: 0.0),
                            ),
                            child: Container(
                                width: 380.0,
                                height: 20.0,
                                padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  border: Border.all(color: Colors.blueAccent)
                                ),
                                child: Slider(
                                  value: 50,
                                  min: 1,
                                  max: 100,
                                  divisions: 100,
                                  activeColor: colors.primaryRed,
                                  inactiveColor: Colors.white,
                                  onChanged: (double newValue) {
                                    print(newValue);
                                  },
                                )
                            )
                        ),
                      ),
                    )
```

Answer (score 69, accepted):

you can fix it with custom trackShape like this:

add this line to SliderTheme data:

````
SliderTheme(
  data: SliderThemeData(
    // here
    trackShape: CustomTrackShape(),
  ),
  child: Slider(
    ```
  ),
),
````

then inside CustomTrackShape() you must write this code:

```
class CustomTrackShape extends RoundedRectSliderTrackShape {
  @override
  Rect getPreferredRect({
    required RenderBox parentBox,
    Offset offset = Offset.zero,
    required SliderThemeData sliderTheme,
    bool isEnabled = false,
    bool isDiscrete = false,
  }) {
    final trackHeight = sliderTheme.trackHeight;
    final trackLeft = offset.dx;
    final trackTop = offset.dy + (parentBox.size.height - trackHeight!) / 2;
    final trackWidth = parentBox.size.width;
    return Rect.fromLTWH(trackLeft, trackTop, trackWidth, trackHeight);
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: In 2023 This is new update

class _SfTrackShape extends SfTrackShape {


  @override
  Rect getPreferredRect(
      RenderBox parentBox, SfSliderThemeData themeData, Offset offset,
      {bool? isActive}) {
    final trackHeight = themeData.activeTrackHeight;
    final trackLeft = offset.dx;
    final trackTop = offset.dy + (parentBox.size.height - trackHeight) / 2;
    final trackWidth = parentBox.size.width;
    return Rect.fromLTWH(trackLeft, trackTop, trackWidth, trackHeight);


  }
}

Answer (score 79):

```
SliderThemeData(overlayShape: SliderComponentShape.noOverlay)
```

or

```
overlayShape: SliderComponentShape.noThumb
```

Default padding is caused by thumb painting and overlay painting, by specifying these properties you will remove them, but you will get zero padding

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SliderThemeData-class.html

Comment: There is still some horizontal padding (

Answer (score 4):

While the accepted solution works reasonably well, the thumb looks too close to the edge when the slider position is at max or min.

[image]

You can address this by adding a custom `thumbShape` and `overlayShape`, which shift the thumb by a fraction of its radius as the slider position gets closer to the edges.

````
class CustomSlider extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SliderTheme(
      data: const SliderThemeData(
        trackShape: CustomSliderTrackShape(),
        thumbShape: CustomSliderThumbShape(),
        overlayShape: CustomSliderOverlayShape(),
      ),
      child: Slider(
        ```
      ),
    );
  }
}

...

class CustomSliderTrackShape extends RoundedRectSliderTrackShape {
  const CustomSliderTrackShape();
  @override
  Rect getPreferredRect({
    required RenderBox parentBox,
    Offset offset = Offset.zero,
    required SliderThemeData sliderTheme,
    bool isEnabled = false,
    bool isDiscrete = false,
  }) {
    final trackHeight = sliderTheme.trackHeight;
    final trackLeft = offset.dx;
    final trackTop = offset.dy + (parentBox.size.height - trackHeight!) / 2;
    final trackWidth = parentBox.size.width;
    return Rect.fromLTWH(trackLeft, trackTop, trackWidth, trackHeight);
  }
}

class CustomSliderThumbShape extends RoundSliderThumbShape {
  const CustomSliderThumbShape({super.enabledThumbRadius = 10.0});

  @override
  void paint(
    PaintingContext context,
    Offset center, {
    required Animation<double> activationAnimation,
    required Animation<double> enableAnimation,
    required bool isDiscrete,
    required TextPainter labelPainter,
    required RenderBox parentBox,
    required SliderThemeData sliderTheme,
    required TextDirection textDirection,
    required double value,
    required double textScaleFactor,
    required Size sizeWithOverflow,
  }) {
    super.paint(context,
        center.translate(-(value - 0.5) / 0.5 * enabledThumbRadius, 0.0),
        activationAnimation: activationAnimation,
        enableAnimation: enableAnimation,
        isDiscrete: isDiscrete,
        labelPainter: labelPainter,
        parentBox: parentBox,
        sliderTheme: sliderTheme,
        textDirection: textDirection,
        value: value,
        textScaleFactor: textScaleFactor,
        sizeWithOverflow: sizeWithOverflow);
  }
}

class CustomSliderOverlayShape extends RoundSliderOverlayShape {
  final double thumbRadius;
  const CustomSliderOverlayShape({this.thumbRadius = 10.0});

  @override
  void paint(
    PaintingContext context,
    Offset center, {
    required Animation<double> activationAnimation,
    required Animation<double> enableAnimation,
    required bool isDiscrete,
    required TextPainter labelPainter,
    required RenderBox parentBox,
    required SliderThemeData sliderTheme,
    required TextDirection textDirection,
    required double value,
    required double textScaleFactor,
    required Size sizeWithOverflow,
  }) {
    super.paint(
        context, center.translate(-(value - 0.5) / 0.5 * thumbRadius, 0.0),
        activationAnimation: activationAnimation,
        enableAnimation: enableAnimation,
        isDiscrete: isDiscrete,
        labelPainter: labelPainter,
        parentBox: parentBox,
        sliderTheme: sliderTheme,
        textDirection: textDirection,
        value: value,
        textScaleFactor: textScaleFactor,
        sizeWithOverflow: sizeWithOverflow);
  }
}
````

More info with additional screenshots: https://medium.com/@tokudu/flutter-removing-default-padding-from-sliders-3f614c12c205

Answer (score 1):

```
class _SfTrackShape extends SfTrackShape {


  @override
  Rect getPreferredRect(
      RenderBox parentBox, SfSliderThemeData themeData, Offset offset,
      {bool? isActive}) {
    final trackHeight = themeData.activeTrackHeight;
    final trackLeft = offset.dx;
    final trackTop = offset.dy + (parentBox.size.height - trackHeight) / 2;
    final trackWidth = parentBox.size.width;
    return Rect.fromLTWH(trackLeft, trackTop, trackWidth, trackHeight);


  }
}
```

Comment: In case anyone is wondering, this code is for SyncFusions Slider not Flutter's default slider. The package is [here](https://pub.dev/packages/syncfusion_flutter_sliders/example)

Answer (score 0):

I recently tackled a layout issue with Flutter's Slider widget where the default padding was throwing off my UI design. The initial look had visible padding at the extremes of the Slider, as shown here:

[image: Initial Slider with Padding]

This wasn't what I was aiming for - I needed the slider track to span the full width of its container.

After some trial and error, I managed to achieve the edge-to-edge track design that I wanted:

[image: Slider after Customization]

The breakthrough came when I defined a custom track shape called `EdgeToEdgeTrackShape`. This class extends `RoundedRectSliderTrackShape` and allows the Slider's track to reach both edges of its container, effectively eliminating the default padding. Here's a snippet of the solution:

```dart
class EdgeToEdgeTrackShape extends RoundedRectSliderTrackShape {
  // Override getPreferredRect to adjust the track's dimensions
  @override
  Rect getPreferredRect({
    required RenderBox parentBox,
    Offset offset = Offset.zero,
    required SliderThemeData sliderTheme,
    bool isEnabled = false,
    bool isDiscrete = false,
  }) {
    final double trackHeight = sliderTheme.trackHeight ?? 2.0;
    final double trackWidth = parentBox.size.width;
    final double trackTop = offset.dy + (parentBox.size.height - trackHeight) / 2;
    return Rect.fromLTWH(offset.dx, trackTop, trackWidth, trackHeight);
  }
}
```

By using this `EdgeToEdgeTrackShape` within the `SliderThemeData`, the Slider now fits perfectly within the horizontal bounds of its container, giving it the seamless edge-to-edge look I was going for. If you're aiming for a similar full-width slider track in your Flutter app, this approach should serve you well!

Full code:

```dart
class AdjustableSlider extends StatefulWidget {
  final double maxValue;
  final ValueChanged<double>? onValueChange;

  const AdjustableSlider({
    super.key,
    this.maxValue = 100.0,
    this.onValueChange,
  });

  @override
  AdjustableSliderState createState() => AdjustableSliderState();
}

class AdjustableSliderState extends State<AdjustableSlider> {
  late double _sliderValue = 0;
  final NumberFormatController _formatController =
      Modular.get<NumberFormatController>();
  late String _formattedMaxValue =
      _formatController.formatNumber(widget.maxValue);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        SliderTheme(
          data: SliderTheme.of(context).copyWith(
            activeTrackColor: const Color(0xFF3263A9),
            inactiveTrackColor: const Color(0xFF3263A9).withOpacity(0.3),
            trackHeight: 2.0,
            thumbColor: const Color(0xFF3263A9),
            thumbShape: RoundedThumbShape(enabledThumbRadius: 12.0),
            overlayColor: const Color(0xFF3263A9).withOpacity(0.3),
            overlayShape: LargeOverlayShape(overlayRadius: 28.0),
            trackShape: EdgeToEdgeTrackShape(),
          ),
          child: Slider(
            value: _sliderValue,
            max: widget.maxValue,
            onChanged: (value) {
              setState(() => _sliderValue = value);
              widget.onValueChange?.call(value);
            },
          ),
        ),
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: [
            const Text('0'),
            Text('R\$ $_formattedMaxValue'),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class EdgeToEdgeTrackShape extends RoundedRectSliderTrackShape {
  @override
  Rect getPreferredRect({
    required RenderBox parentBox,
    Offset offset = Offset.zero,
    required SliderThemeData sliderTheme,
    bool isEnabled = false,
    bool isDiscrete = false,
  }) {
    final trackHeight = sliderTheme.trackHeight ?? 2.0;
    final trackWidth = parentBox.size.width;
    final trackTop = offset.dy + (parentBox.size.height - trackHeight) / 2;
    return Rect.fromLTWH(offset.dx, trackTop, trackWidth, trackHeight);
  }
}

class CustomSliderThumbShape extends RoundSliderThumbShape {
  const CustomSliderThumbShape({super.enabledThumbRadius = 10.0});

  @override
  void paint(
    PaintingContext context,
    Offset center, {
    required Animation<double> activationAnimation,
    required Animation<double> enableAnimation,
    required bool isDiscrete,
    required TextPainter labelPainter,
    required RenderBox parentBox,
    required SliderThemeData sliderTheme,
    required TextDirection textDirection,
    required double value,
    required double textScaleFactor,
    required Size sizeWithOverflow,
  }) {
    super.paint(
      context,
      center.translate(-(value - 0.5) / 0.5 * enabledThumbRadius, 0.0),
      activationAnimation: activationAnimation,
      enableAnimation: enableAnimation,
      isDiscrete: isDiscrete,
      labelPainter: labelPainter,
      parentBox: parentBox,
      sliderTheme: sliderTheme,
      textDirection: textDirection,
      value: value,
      textScaleFactor: textScaleFactor,
      sizeWithOverflow: sizeWithOverflow,
    );
  }
}

class SliderTrackShape extends RoundedRectSliderTrackShape {
  @override
  Rect getPreferredRect({
    required RenderBox parentBox,
    Offset offset = Offset.zero,
    required SliderThemeData sliderTheme,
    bool isEnabled = false,
    bool isDiscrete = false,
  }) =>
      Rect.fromLTWH(
        offset.dx,
        offset.dy + (parentBox.size.height - sliderTheme.trackHeight!) / 2,
        parentBox.size.width,
        sliderTheme.trackHeight!,
      );
}

class RoundedThumbShape extends RoundSliderThumbShape {
  @override
  final double enabledThumbRadius;

  RoundedThumbShape({
    this.enabledThumbRadius = 10.0,
  }) : super(
          enabledThumbRadius: enabledThumbRadius,
        );

  @override
  void paint(
    PaintingContext context,
    Offset center, {
    required Animation<double> activationAnimation,
    required Animation<double> enableAnimation,
    required bool isDiscrete,
    required TextPainter labelPainter,
    required RenderBox parentBox,
    required SliderThemeData sliderTheme,
    required TextDirection textDirection,
    required double value,
    required double textScaleFactor,
    required Size sizeWithOverflow,
  }) {
    super.paint(
      context,
      center,
      activationAnimation: activationAnimation,
      enableAnimation: enableAnimation,
      isDiscrete: isDiscrete,
      labelPainter: labelPainter,
      parentBox: parentBox,
      sliderTheme: sliderTheme,
      textDirection: textDirection,
      value: value,
      textScaleFactor: textScaleFactor,
      sizeWithOverflow: sizeWithOverflow,
    );
  }
}

class LargeOverlayShape extends RoundSliderOverlayShape {
  final double overlayRadius;

  LargeOverlayShape({this.overlayRadius = 24.0})
      : super(overlayRadius: overlayRadius);
}
```