# How can I remove the default horizontal padding on Flutter's RangeSlider?

Tags: flutter

I am making a Flutter app where I have a simple RangeSlider for people to rate from 0-100. However, RangeSlider seems to have a default padding on the left and right ends, and I am unable to remove this in any way.

I have tried placing it in Expanded, Container with custom width, and SizedBox with custom width, but problem seems to stem from the way RangeSlider was coded. Any solutions?

```
SliderTheme(
  data: SliderThemeData(
    thumbColor: accentColor,
    disabledThumbColor: accentColor,
    overlayColor: accentColor,
    disabledActiveTrackColor: accentColor,
    disabledInactiveTickMarkColor: accentColor,
    disabledInactiveTrackColor: accentColor,
    trackHeight: 0.4,
    thumbShape:
        RoundSliderThumbShape(enabledThumbRadius: 4.0),
  ),
  child: Slider(
    min: 0,
    max: 100,
    value: 10,
    onChanged: null,
  ),
),
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65662764/21590733 This should help